# Typechecking in vanilla JS – why use typeof for string but typeof .matches for booleans?

Tags: javascript

I'm checking some variables from localStorage before continuing my script. First this:

```
const hasStorageValue = typeof storageValue === 'string'
```

Then I read an example of something similar for booleans. Like this:

```
const hasStorageValue = typeof storageValue.matches === 'boolean'
```

Curious if the two uses are equivalent or if there's another requirement for booleans than for strings?

Edit: Found back to the original code I was looking at. It's like this:

```
const mql = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  const hasMediaQueryPreference = typeof mql.matches === 'boolean';
```

From "A first pass" [in this article](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/dark-mode/).

window.matchMedia() returns an object, as Nicolas correctly points to in the comments:

[image]

I mixed `element.matches()` with `window.matchMedia().matches` – which was the reason for asking here.

Comment: "matches" isn't some standard javascript thing. The second example has an object with a property named `matches` on it, and you're checking if that property is a boolean.

Comment: `(typeof anyexpression) === 'string that is returned by typeof'` -- what is the 'anyexpression' expression's resulting value?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how `typeof` works? You can find that out faster by playing around in the console than by asking here.

Comment: Aha! I missed that .matches is not the same as element.matches() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches. Thanks @NicholasTower for pointing out that the code I'm looking at refers to an object and not a built-in method. So this means I could use typeof storageValue === ... in both cases, I guess.